# Cordova build error ANDROID_HOME

Tags: java, android, cordova, path, android-sdk-tools

Hello stackoverflow gang,

I'm trying to build android sample app with command "cordova build android" and always get Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' as you can see in attached image I setup path properly. I've no idea what I doing wrong. Could you please suggest me how to solve this problem.

/* Add more info */

I'm using mac osx 10.11 .
I can run android command from terminal and open Android SDK Manager.
I can build ios successful with command "cordova build ios"

Thank you

Karun

[image: Cordova build error ANDROID_HOME]

Answer (score 0):

Set path in Environmental variable

In windows:-

System properties->Environmental variable->System variables->click new and add

variable name->ANDROID_HOME

variable path->sdk path (i.e.  .../sdk)

Comment: I think you way is for Windows. I'm using mac osx 10.11

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue on my Mac 10.9.5 while building `android` app. Go through the below steps:

First download the android sdk for mac from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip).

Then in `.bash_profile` file, set `path` like below:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/anand.gupta/android-sdk-macosx

export PATH=/Users/anand.gupta/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools:/Users/anand.gupta/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/anand.gupta/android-sdk-macosx/tools:$PATH

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Now download Android 4.4.2(API 19) from your android manager. (Optional)

Make sure you have `ant` installed. Check using: `ant -version`.

You can use the latest `cordova` but if the issue is still persist then use cordova (3.5.0-0.2.7), but if you want to upgrade or downgrade the cordova, remove the existing one using:-

```
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
```

Then install cordova without sudo

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@3.5.0-0.2.7
```

And after downloading the android(4.4.2), create an android virtual device using the command:

```
android avd
```

Let me know if helps solving your problem or not. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your suggestions. Finally I found the answer just grant permission to my project by using command "sudo chown -R macuser /Users/macuser/applications/myproject" and using build command without sudo "cordova build android"

[image: Success]